# error after change my application into maintenance mode in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

im learn ebook getting started with laravel 4,everything is OK before i turn my application into maintenance mode with command php artisan down, when i try to change into live mode with command php artisan up, why i got error in my index.blade .php??

here my index.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('header')
@if(isset($breed))
{{link_to('/', 'Back to the overview')}}
@endif
<h2>
All @if(isset($breed)) {{$breed->name}} @endif Cats
<a href="{{URL::to('cats/create?_token='.csrf_token())}}" class="btn btn-primarypull-right">
Add a new cat
</a>
</h2>
@stop
@section('content')
@foreach($cats as $cat)
<div class="cat">
<a href="{{url('cats/'.$cat->id)}}">
<strong> {{{$cat->name}}} </strong> - {{{$cat->breed->name}}}
</a></div>
@endforeach
@stop
```

this is my routes

```
    Route::get('cats', function()
{
    $cats = Cat::all();
    return View::make('cats.index')->with('cats', $cats);
});
```

this my error location

```
</a>
</h2>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<?php foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
<div class="cat">
**<a href="<?php echo url('cats/'.$cat->id); ?>">
<strong> <?php echo e($cat->name); ?> </strong> - <?php echo e($cat->breed->name); ?>**
</a></div>
```

Exception message: Trying to get property of non-object

please help to solve this problem :(

Comment: What is `$cats`, it might not be defined or not defined correctly.

Comment: maybe the $cats come from my routes?everythings ok before i run "php artisan down":(

Comment: Does every cat have a breed assigned? Try `{{{ ($cat->breed != null ? $cat->breed->name : '') }}}` instead of `{{{$cat->breed->name}}}`

Comment: thanks for all the advice to me, i've solve this problem, i've relation between cats table and breed table, and each row in my cats table doesn't contain breed_id and after i delete this row, everythings come back normally :D,thanks for all..